# How do I change the company in Web Payments on a Facebook App after transferring it to my FB account

Tags: facebook

a third party company recently transferred its Facebook app into my company's Facebook account. We have complete ownership of the App on Facebook, (None of the previous company's accounts are associated with the app anymore) but we cannot change the company in the Web payments section of the App, meaning all payments made through Facebook are still going to the previous company.

Has anyone had experience with this?

Comment: You probably need to figure out who their Payout Account Admin was, resp. have that role transferred to you as well. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/payout_faq#faq_856912804470885

Comment: Following those steps would make me an admin on their Facebook dev account and let me edit their bank and company info, impacting the apps they still own. I don't think they want that. 

My company's payout account is already correctly configured and already the admin for it. I need to switch the App to use the existing company setup I already have on my account.

Comment: So what exactly does _“we cannot change the company”_ mean then?